# In a mixed model: Is there any statistical problem of using a random variable that is highly corelated to my variable of response?

Tags: mixed-model

I would like first to mention that I am not statistician but I work with lineal mixed model and like to know more about statistic behind them.

Here my question:
I have a mixed model where I have response variable (e.g. protein content), and I have a set of variables (from spectra decomposition) that are highly corelated with protein. I am using all this spectra as random effect in the model. I run the model using REML and the model converged OK. I wonder if from an statistical point of view is any issue on using these highly corelated variable as model effect. The final aim of my model is prediction.

Comment: said in another way, the question refers to the implicancies of correlation between predictors and predicted variable.

Answer (score 3):

The primary motivation for using a mixed-effects model is to account for the correlation in your outcome variable within the levels of a grouping factor. Two examples are repeated measurements over time taken on the same sample unit (i.e., longitudinal data) and outcome measurements in a multi-level design (e.g., outcomes recorded in pupils from the same school and schools from the same district).

It is unclear from your description if you need to account for such correlations. In particular, are the protein measurements within the same spectra level expected to be correlated?

Comment: +1 I would phrase the concerns differently, "Given that your goal is prediction then all the classic assumptions wrt independence of the predictors fall away." That said, the only clarification is confirmation that the spectra aren't a linear combination or some other product of the response.  If so, then one solution to that is to take lagged functions of same.

Comment: Goo to see this comment as it help to clear my point. The issue behind is that the spectra could be a linear combination of the response. Is this a problem for the model? If so, Do you have any idea on why this could represent a problem?

Comment: Linear combinations of the target are simply a different expression of same. Iow, it's like using the target to predict the target. As noted, taking a lag of the spectra would solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me any book/reference where to read more about lag functions? I Google it but it seems to be a term used in different areas.

Comment: Koyck models are one example...Kotler develops it in one of his books.